# Why I can't see my iOS app appears in Location Service setting?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, geolocation

Does any know why my iOS app doesn't appears in Location Service setting?

My app was created by using ActionScript 3 and AIR 13 trying to run on iOS6 and iOS7.

Thank you!

Comment: I never use ActionScript 3 and AIR 13. Do you have any settings related to Background Modes - location updates?

Comment: I have tried to add this:
<InfoAdditions> 
    <![CDATA[ 
        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key> 
        <array> 
               <string>location</string> 
         </array> 
    ]]> 
</InfoAdditions>

into the Application Descriptor file, but still didn't work.

Comment: Do you set NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground property to true? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html

Comment: I don't know what have I done, I was trying to load Google map from my app, then a popup message appear to ask for location access permission from Google Map on behalf of my app, I select YES, after that I can see my app appears on the Location Service setting. :)

Comment: @Ricky, thanks for your efforts anyway. :)

Comment: Good to know that you can make it work. No problem. ;) You may put an answer below there and mark your own answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck on this as I was...

Tried a bunch of things, no luck... What worked was posted here https://forums.adobe.com/message/4718390

You must set the event listener before you do anything with the Geolocation object (even check if it is muted)...

geo.addEventListener( GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onLocationUpdate );
This is what requests permissions on the device to use gps/location services.

Hopefully this helps anyone else that is ever stuck with this issue...

Derek